# How to hash realmdb password

Tags: realm, password-hash, createuser

I want to create/update realmdb password on path `__password`.

I cannot find clear documentation about it, i just explore realm studio and realmdb graphql API.

From realm studio i found **salt, digest (sha512), and hash**.
From that key i produce sha512 hash with https://www.convertstring.com/Hash/SHA512.

the problem is, character length from sha512 just 128 character. i tried to compare with other hash password, they have 684 character.

the other key i found inside path `__password` such as iterations and keyLength, i don't know what that for.

actually i can use this API for create user.
`Realm.Sync.User.login([**serverURL**],Realm.Sync.Credentials.usernamePassword([**username**], [**password**], true));`

but i want to update password too. there is no documentation about changing password.

the question is :

- How i can produce sha512 with output 684 character ?
- How to update realm password directly to path __password ?
- What is best practice to update user password ?